# In iOS, is it possible to obtain waveform or spectrum data of the current track? eg: equalizer

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, waveform, equalizer

Is it possible to read the spectrum data from the currently playing track in iOS? For example, to make an equalizer similar to the one in iTunes?

Answer (score 3):

Apple has a sample program, "aurioTouch," which can display time and frequency domain waveforms.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: thanks, however this uses the microphone input. could you recommend tweaks to the code to get it to read from the device's music player?

Comment: It moved here: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch2/Introduction/Intro.html